# SeleniumLibrary.Click Element with modifier CTRL is performing a Right Click+Ctrl in robotframework execution

Tags: selenium, click, robotframework

I need to multi-select elements in a UI using the Ctrl+Click option using robot framework via VNC server execution, but it is performing a Right Mouse Click + Ctrl which is not the multiselect usecase I am expecting....

Command used :-

```
Click Element  <Xpath Locator>  modifier=CTRL
```

Versions Used :-

```
robotframework (3.0.4)
robotframework-selenium2library (3.0.0)
robotframework-seleniumlibrary (4.1.0)
selenium (3.141.0)
```

Could you please help me resolve this issue of Right Mouse Click..?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using latest Selenium library not Selenium2. Double check if locator is correct.

This keyword is correct:

```
Click Element  <Xpath Locator>  CTRL
```